# HTML auto height for no space content

Tags: html, css

I have 2 div tags in HTML with same class ".block"

```
Problem:
```

div will auto adjust its height only if the content within it have space or break in it. Else div will not auto adjust its height when we have running text without any space or break.

How do we give auto height with HTML and CSS in this scenario with out using any client side programming.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/n8c12uut/

HTML:

```
<div id="blockContainer">
    <div class="block">TESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTESTTEST</div>        
    <div class="block">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#blockContainer { background-color: #e5fef5; padding: 10px; }
.block { background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add CSS `word-wrap:break-word;` to `.block`:

```
.block {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/n8c12uut/1/)**